# Script sending form on my behalf

Tags: javascript, automation, vps

I have an account in patient portal on which I can search for available dates for an appointment and then book the visit with a doctor. There are very few available dates though so I end up entering the portal and refreshing the search, which is very tiresome. I've been thinking about it for a moment and have came up with an idea that there could be a script run on some VPS, which will sends periodically forms with fabricated data on my behalf and when available date which I am interested in came up I would be notified by email.

I don't know much about html and javascript but what I found in page source is this:

- button search call FilterFormSubmit():

  ```
  <input type="submit" class="button pretty" onclick=" javascript: FilterFormSubmit(); return false;" value="Search">
  ```
- this function looks like this:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                        
    function FilterFormSubmit() {                                                                                                                        
      var searchVisitsBreakdownReservation = 'false' == 'true' ? true : false;                                                                           

          if (!searchVisitsBreakdownReservation) {                                                                                                       
              window.isMyLink = true;                                                                                                                    
              $("#advancedResevation").submit();                                                                                                         
              return true;                                                                                                                               
          } else {                                                                                                                                       
            $("#SearchVisitsBreakdownReservation").show();                                                                                               
            return false;                                                                                                                                
          }                                                                                                                                              
      }                                                                                                                                                  
  </script>
  ```

And on this step I was stuck: I didn't understand what this line `$("#advancedResevation").submit();` does.

My next step was to analyze packets in wireshark. I thought I could just fabricate packet which I can send to the patient portal's server, receive response and then parse the response in proper way, but unfortunately packets is send by TLSv1.1.

My question is: what should I learn and where should I search to make my idea come true?

Answer (score 0):

`onclick=" javascript: FilterFormSubmit();` is wrong. The contents of an `onclick` are ALREADY javascript. it should be just

```
onclick="FilterFormSubmit; return false"
```

The javascript pseudo-url is for usage in the `href`:

```
<a href="javascript:FilterFormSubmit();">
   ^^^^
```

Comment: I didn't write this code - I just quoted it from the page source.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and dom element lookup (xpath, css selector). In this way, you do not need to probe js resource of the website or details of the request.

Or use tools like firebug(an extension for firefox) to get the details of submitted request. Then you may fake request without browsers.

Comment: I will give them a try. I also wonder how I would cope with automatically log in (on start and when session expires) with my credentials.

Comment: Check if you are redirected to login page, enter you account info if so.